# How can I run a set of unit tests against two different implementations of an interface in MS Test?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I have two services which both store data to disk and read it from there.
One is using SQL, the other one is pure file based. Both implement my interface `IDataStorage`.

One layer above is a facade class that does processing to the data before passing it on to the `IDataStorage` implementation.

I have a set of unit tests for the facade class in Visual Studio 2012.

Problem is that there is currently a

```
#define USE_SQL_STORAGE
```

and

```
#define USE_FILE_STORAGE
```

in the first line of the test class that decides which concrete `IDataStorage` implementation gets passed to the facade class.
I always test both implementations manually by changing the defined storage.

Is there a way to automate this and have both implementations tested against the same set of tests **without having to maintain the same tests twice**?

Answer (score 0):

Found it out myself.

The solution is to create an abstract base test class:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseTest
{
public abstract IDataStorage GetService();


[TestInitialize]
public virtual void Init()
{
this.service = GetService();
}
}
```

and then have two implementations of the bas class:

```
[TestClass]
public SQLiteTest : BaseTest
{
public override IDataStorage GetService()
{
return new SQLiteStorage();
}
}

[TestClass]
public FileTest : BaseTest
{
public override IDataStorage GetService()
{
return new FileStorage();
}
}
```

Then the two concrete implementations will show in the list of test cases but not the abstract base.